# Как добавить некоторые данные в поток?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

У меня есть основной поток, в котором выполняется код. 
Как мне не прерывая поток добавить в него элемент?

Примерный код:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
from urllib import request
import time, threading, sys


class ThreadWork(QtCore.QObject):
    flagFinished = False 
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    sendLenOst = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendLenVsego = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendVizov = pyqtSignal(int)
    captchaSend = pyqtSignal(int)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startText(self, text):
        self.groups = []
        self.textS = text

        def finishedText():
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finishedText()

    def osnovaNew(self):
        while not self.flagFinished:
            f = open("groups.txt")
            f = f.read()
            x = f.split("\n")
            if len(f) > 3:
                self.sendLenVsego.emit(len(x))
                while len(x) != 0:
                    xs = x[0]
                    if xs == "1":
                        print("vhod")
                        self.captchaSend.emit(1)
                        # Сюда нужно добавить полученный текст с QLineEdit класса Dialog
                        break
                    elif xs != 1:
                        x.pop(0)
                        self.sendLenOst.emit(len(x))
                    QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)
                    fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                    if fl: break
            else:
                self.sendVizov.emit(1)
                self.flagFinished = True
                fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                if fl: break
            self.flagFinished = True

    def flagFinish(self, flagFinished):
        self.flagFinished = flagFinished
        return self.flagFinished

class joinGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.threads = None
        self.groups = []
        self.sendText = "Text"
        self.openOrNo = 0
        self.ostatok = 0

        self.userName = QLabel(self)
        self.userName.setGeometry(10, 10, 380, 40)

        self.stopBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.stopBtn.setGeometry(210, 60, 180, 40)
        self.stopBtn.setText("Stop")
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.sendStop)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)

        self.startBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.startBtn.setGeometry(10, 60, 180, 40)
        self.startBtn.setText("Start")
        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.joining)

        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
        self.label1.setGeometry(10, 255, 180, 35)

        self.label2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
        self.label2.setGeometry(210, 255, 180, 35)

    def joining(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(True)

        if not self.threads:
            self.worker = ThreadWork()
            self.worker.sendLenOst.connect(self.processTextOst)
            self.worker.sendLenVsego.connect(self.processTextVsego)
            self.worker.sendVizov.connect(self.messageOpen)
            self.worker.captchaSend.connect(self.openCaptcha)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.stoping)
            thread = threading.Thread(
                target = self.worker.startText,
                args = [self.sendText],
                daemon = True
            ).start()

    def processTextOst(self, text):
        self.ostatok = text
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(self.ostatok))

    def processTextVsego(self, text):
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            {0}".format(text))
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(text))

    def openCaptcha(self, text):
        print("Captcha")
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.dialog.exec()
        self.openOrNo = 2

    def messageOpen(self, text):
        self.openOrNo = text

    def stoping(self):
        if self.openOrNo == 0:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
            self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
            msg.setText("Отлично. Остаток: " + str(self.ostatok))
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
        elif self.openOrNo == 1:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            msg.setText("Пусто. Проверьте файл <b>groups.txt</b>")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
            self.openOrNo = 1

    def sendStop(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.flagFinished = True
        self.worker.flagFinish(self.worker.flagFinished)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(340, 95)

        self.line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.setGeometry(145, 5, 190, 40)
        self.line.setPlaceholderText("Ввод капчи")

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить капчу", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(5, 50, 330, 40)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.push)     

    @pyqtSlot()
    def push(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = joinGroup()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Сделайте пример вышей реализации многопоточности.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я плохо понимаю что у вас происходит в циклах класса `ThreadWork`.
Там ли вы читаете файл `groups.txt`, где вы его закрываите?
Что такое `len(f) > 3` ? ...

Но я попробовал добавить элемент в поток и отметил места, где внес изменения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
#from urllib import request
import threading

class ThreadWork(QtCore.QObject):
    flagFinished = False 
    started      = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished     = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    sendLenOst   = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendLenVsego = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendVizov    = pyqtSignal(int)
    captchaSend  = pyqtSignal(int)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startText(self, text):
        self.groups = []
        self.textS = text

        def finishedText():
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finishedText()

    def osnovaNew(self):
        while not self.flagFinished:
            f = open("groups.txt")
            f = f.read()
            x = f.split("\n")
#            print(f"len(f)-{len(f)}, x-{x}")
            if len(f) > 3:                         # ??? 
                self.sendLenVsego.emit(len(x))
                while len(x) != 0:
                    xs = x[0]


                    if xs == "1":
                        print("vhod")
                        self.captchaSend.emit(1)
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                        
# Сюда нужно добавить полученный текст с QLineEdit класса Dialog
                        QtCore.QThread.msleep(5000)                  # какая-то пауза для ввода captchi
                        print("self.textS: ", self.textS)            # <--- проверти вывод
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        
                        break

                    elif xs != 1:
                        x.pop(0)
                        self.sendLenOst.emit(len(x))

                    QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                 
                    fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                    if fl: break
            else:
                self.sendVizov.emit(1)
                self.flagFinished = True
                fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                if fl: break
            self.flagFinished = True

    def flagFinish(self, flagFinished):
        self.flagFinished = flagFinished
        return self.flagFinished

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def sendCaptcha(self, text):
        self.textS = text
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        


class joinGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.threads = None
        self.groups = []
        self.sendText = "Text"
        self.openOrNo = 0
        self.ostatok  = 0

        self.userName = QLabel(self)
        self.userName.setGeometry(10, 10, 380, 40)

        self.stopBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.stopBtn.setGeometry(210, 60, 180, 40)
        self.stopBtn.setText("Stop")
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.sendStop)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)

        self.startBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.startBtn.setGeometry(10, 60, 180, 40)
        self.startBtn.setText("Start")
        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.joining)

        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
        self.label1.setGeometry(10, 255, 180, 35)

        self.label2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
        self.label2.setGeometry(210, 255, 180, 35)

    def joining(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(True)

        if not self.threads:
            self.worker = ThreadWork()
            self.worker.sendLenOst.connect(self.processTextOst)
            self.worker.sendLenVsego.connect(self.processTextVsego)
            self.worker.sendVizov.connect(self.messageOpen)
            self.worker.captchaSend.connect(self.openCaptcha)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.stoping)

            thread = threading.Thread(
                target = self.worker.startText,
                args = [self.sendText],
                daemon = True
            ).start()

    def processTextOst(self, text):
        self.ostatok = text
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(self.ostatok))

    def processTextVsego(self, text):
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            {0}".format(text))
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(text))

    def openCaptcha(self, text):
        print("Captcha")
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)  # + self
        self.dialog.exec()
        self.openOrNo = 2

    def messageOpen(self, text):
        self.openOrNo = text

    def stoping(self):
        if self.openOrNo == 0:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
            self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
            msg.setText("Отлично. Остаток: " + str(self.ostatok))
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
        elif self.openOrNo == 1:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            msg.setText("Пусто. Проверьте файл <b>groups.txt</b>")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
            self.openOrNo = 1

    def sendStop(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.flagFinished = True
        self.worker.flagFinish(self.worker.flagFinished)


class Dialog(QDialog):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.setFixedSize(340, 95)
        self.line = QLineEdit(self, placeholderText="Введите значение для отправки.")
        self.line.setGeometry(145, 5, 190, 40)
        self.line.setPlaceholderText("Ввод капчи")

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить капчу", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(5, 50, 330, 40)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.push)     

    @pyqtSlot()
    def push(self):
        self.parent.worker.sendCaptcha(self.line.text())                  # <<<+++++++++++++++++++
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = joinGroup()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А если в функции openCaptcha * self.dialog = Dialog(self) * передаются дополнительные параметры? Как передать их вместе с self?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
#from urllib import request
import threading

class ThreadWork(QtCore.QObject):
    flagFinished = False 
    started      = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished     = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    sendLenOst   = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendLenVsego = pyqtSignal(int)
    sendVizov    = pyqtSignal(int)
    captchaSend  = pyqtSignal(int)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startText(self, text):
        self.groups = []
        self.textS = text

        def finishedText():
            self.finished.emit()

        self.osnovaNew()
        finishedText()

    def osnovaNew(self):
        while not self.flagFinished:
            f = open("groups.txt")
            f = f.read()
            x = f.split("\n")
#            print(f"len(f)-{len(f)}, x-{x}")
            if len(f) > 3:                         # ??? 
                self.sendLenVsego.emit(len(x))
                while len(x) != 0:
                    xs = x[0]


                    if xs == "1":
                        print("vhod")
                        self.captchaSend.emit(1)
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                        
# Сюда нужно добавить полученный текст с QLineEdit класса Dialog
                        QtCore.QThread.msleep(5000)                  # какая-то пауза для ввода captchi
                        print("self.textS: ", self.textS)            # <--- проверти вывод
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        
                        break

                    elif xs != 1:
                        x.pop(0)
                        self.sendLenOst.emit(len(x))

                    QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                 
                    fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                    if fl: break
            else:
                self.sendVizov.emit(1)
                self.flagFinished = True
                fl = self.flagFinish(self.flagFinished)
                if fl: break
            self.flagFinished = True

    def flagFinish(self, flagFinished):
        self.flagFinished = flagFinished
        return self.flagFinished

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def sendCaptcha(self, text):
        self.textS = text
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        


class joinGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.threads = None
        self.groups = []
        self.sendText = "Text"
        self.openOrNo = 0
        self.ostatok  = 0

        self.userName = QLabel(self)
        self.userName.setGeometry(10, 10, 380, 40)

        self.stopBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.stopBtn.setGeometry(210, 60, 180, 40)
        self.stopBtn.setText("Stop")
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.sendStop)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)

        self.startBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.startBtn.setGeometry(10, 60, 180, 40)
        self.startBtn.setText("Start")
        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.joining)

        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
        self.label1.setGeometry(10, 255, 180, 35)

        self.label2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
        self.label2.setGeometry(210, 255, 180, 35)

    def joining(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(True)

        if not self.threads:
            self.worker = ThreadWork()
            self.worker.sendLenOst.connect(self.processTextOst)
            self.worker.sendLenVsego.connect(self.processTextVsego)
            self.worker.sendVizov.connect(self.messageOpen)
            self.worker.captchaSend.connect(self.openCaptcha)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.stoping)

            thread = threading.Thread(
                target = self.worker.startText,
                args = [self.sendText],
                daemon = True
            ).start()

    def processTextOst(self, text):
        self.ostatok = text
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(self.ostatok))

    def processTextVsego(self, text):
        self.label1.setText("  Всего:            {0}".format(text))
        self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     {0}    ".format(text))

    def openCaptcha(self, text):
        print("Captcha")

        text = "Captcha"                                           # +++
        self.dialog = Dialog(text, self)                           # +++ text, self
        self.dialog.exec()
        self.openOrNo = 2

    def messageOpen(self, text):
        self.openOrNo = text

    def stoping(self):
        if self.openOrNo == 0:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.label1.setText("  Всего:            0")
            self.label2.setText("  Осталось:     0    ")
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
            msg.setText("Отлично. Остаток: " + str(self.ostatok))
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
        elif self.openOrNo == 1:
            self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            msg.setText("Пусто. Проверьте файл <b>groups.txt</b>")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msg.exec_()
            self.openOrNo = 1

    def sendStop(self):
        self.startBtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.flagFinished = True
        self.worker.flagFinish(self.worker.flagFinished)


class Dialog(QDialog):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__()
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):                         # +++    
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        print("\ntext={}, \nparent={}\n".format(text, parent))     # +++
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.setFixedSize(340, 95)
        self.line = QLineEdit(self, placeholderText="Введите значение для отправки.")
        self.line.setGeometry(145, 5, 190, 40)
        self.line.setPlaceholderText("Ввод капчи")

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить капчу", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(5, 50, 330, 40)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.push)     

    @pyqtSlot()
    def push(self):
        self.parent.worker.sendCaptcha(self.line.text())              # <---
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = joinGroup()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А если в функции openCaptcha 
* self.dialog = Dialog(self) * передаются дополнительные параметры? 
Как передать их вместе с self?

Comment: @djimbosfan смотрите строки прокомментированные `# +++`